# Enable camera without Raspi-config

Tags: camera

I would like to enable the raspberry pi camera without using raspi-config, as I need to do this in an automated bash script.

Anyone know how?

ended up pulling this out of raspi-config

```
#!/bin/bash

set_config_var() {
  lua - "$1" "$2" "$3" <<EOF > "$3.bak"
local key=assert(arg[1])
local value=assert(arg[2])
local fn=assert(arg[3])
local file=assert(io.open(fn))
local made_change=false
for line in file:lines() do
  if line:match("^#?%s*"..key.."=.*$") then
    line=key.."="..value
    made_change=true
  end
  print(line)
end

if not made_change then
  print(key.."="..value)
end
EOF
mv "$3.bak" "$3"
}




[ -e /boot/config.txt ] || touch /boot/config.txt

set_config_var start_x 1 /boot/config.txt
set_config_var gpu_mem 128 /boot/config.txt
sed /boot/config.txt -i -e "s/^startx/#startx/"
sed /boot/config.txt -i -e "s/^fixup_file/#fixup_file/"
```

Answer (score 3):

Raspi-Config is pointing at /boot/config.txt where the string start_x=# is located in the bottom of the document. the "#" represent either a "0" or a "1". 0 = Camera disabled and 1 = Camera enabled.

I solved this by making a script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep "start_x=1" /boot/config.txt
if grep "start_x=1" /boot/config.txt
then
        exit
else
        sed -i "s/start_x=0/start_x=1/g" /boot/config.txt
        reboot
fi
exit
```

Don't forget to chmod the script so that you can execute it, and after that run script as root.

Comment: Why would starting X have anything to do with the camera?

Answer (score 2):

Generally you can use `lsmod` command for listing kernel modules names and after that you can install module with `insmod [module_name]`. `rmmod [module_name]` command is for removing modules.

Comment: I think `modprobe` would be the command of choice. It resolves dependencies, if there are any.

Comment: I agree with you @Arne .

Answer (score 2):

Based on [How could one automate the raspbian raspi-config setup?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28907/how-could-one-automate-the-raspbian-raspi-config-setup) this should work:

```
sudo raspi-config nonint do_camera 0
```

(Also, it works for me.)