# Where can I learn about the raspi-config noint parameters?

Tags: raspi-config

I recently learned about the `raspi-config noint` parameter from [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28907/how-could-one-automate-the-raspbian-raspi-config-setup). This is perfect for my needs but now I need to figure out which parameters to send.

I'm trying to change two things: the resolution and the keyboard layout. Where can I learn what parameters I need to type in?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK this is not documented.

```
cat /usr/bin/raspi-config | grep  "do_"
```

will show the possible functions.

Comment: Thank you. That allowed me to find `do_resolution` and `do_configure_keyboard`, but how do I find out what value I need to provide? Maybe I could change it to what I want using the interactive way and then finding out what that value is?

Comment: @GFL read the section in /usr/bin/raspi-config - there are >2000 lines of code, but last time I looked the functions were reasonably clear. Never done this, because I don't actually see the point - I just configure an image once.

Answer (score 0):

All options are now listed on the Raspberry Pi config for `rpi-config`:

https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#raspi-config-cli-commands

Current list:

- do_audio
- do_audioconf
- do_blanking
- do_boot_behaviour
- do_boot_order
- do_boot_rom
- do_boot_splash
- do_boot_wait
- do_browser
- do_change_locale
- do_change_pass
- do_change_timezone
- do_composite
- do_configure_keyboard
- do_expand_rootfs
- do_fan
- do_hostname
- do_i2c
- do_leds
- do_memory_split
- do_net_names
- do_onewire
- do_overclock
- do_overlayfs
- do_overscan_kms
- do_pi4video
- do_proxy
- do_rgpio
- do_serial_cons
- do_serial_hw
- do_spi
- do_ssh
- do_update
- do_vnc
- do_vnc_resolution
- do_wayland
- do_wifi_country
- do_wifi_ssid_passphrase

Created with

```
curl https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html | egrep -o "do_[^ ]*" | sort | uniq
```