# Boot into GUI by default without raspi-config, command-line only

Tags: raspbian, gui, pixel

I installed after the light raspbian version `sudo apt install raspberrypi-ui-mods` which installs pixel desktop manager. After that I'm trying to have an automated script that enables the GUI without having to pass through `raspi-config`. Did not find any way to do that, which configuration file does it go to modify!! I'd like it without user auto-login

Comment: That command doesn't install a desktop - it updates the existing. If you have lite there is lots of other stuff needed. Incidentally PIXEL was a short lived kluge of LXDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the script that `raspi-config` runs when you enable the GUI without autologin:

```
      systemctl set-default graphical.target
      ln -fs /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
      rm /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf
      sed /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf -i -e "s/^autologin-user=.*/#autologin-user=/"
```

You may need to edit a different config file if you have a different desktop manager.

Comment: any location for this file?

Comment: @PhilippeGachoud Sorry, I don't know. A quick googling suggest that Pixel is just a rebranded `lightdm` (just like Raspbian is a rebranded Debian), so the config file should still be `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. Still, you should check which DM you actually have.

Answer (score 3):

If the reason why you don't want to use `raspi-config` is because you want to automate it and not have to go through the interactive menu, you can also use the script in a noninteractive way (see also [this Q&A e.g.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/47958/121607)):

```
raspi-config nonint function options
```

will directly execute the internally defined function that does the actual work, and which in the interactive mode would be triggered by your menu choice.

In your case

```
raspi-config nonint do_boot_behaviour B3
```

will enable the graphical login, just as if you had chosen "1: System Options" -> "S5: Boot/Auto Login" -> "B3: Desktop" in the interactive mode. If you want to choose the "auto-login" graphical boot, use

```
raspi-config nonint do_boot_behaviour B4
```

instead.